# String count with overlapping occurrences

Tags: python, string, search

What's the best way to count the number of occurrences of a given string, including overlap in Python? This is one way:

```
def function(string, str_to_search_for):
      count = 0
      for x in xrange(len(string) - len(str_to_search_for) + 1):
           if string[x:x+len(str_to_search_for)] == str_to_search_for:
                count += 1
      return count


function('1011101111','11')
```

This method returns 5.

Is there a better way in Python?

Comment: Better in what way?

Comment: The canonical is [Count number of occurrences of a substring in a string](/questions/8899905), which covers how to count both overlapping and non-overlapping occurrences.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Well, this *might* be faster since it does the comparing in C:

```
def occurrences(string, sub):
    count = start = 0
    while True:
        start = string.find(sub, start) + 1
        if start > 0:
            count+=1
        else:
            return count
```

Answer (score 57):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '1011101111'
>>> len(re.findall('(?=11)', text))
5
```

If you didn't want to load the whole list of matches into memory, which would never be a problem! you could do this if you really wanted:

```
>>> sum(1 for _ in re.finditer('(?=11)', text))
5
```

As a function ([`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) makes sure the substring doesn't interfere with the regex):

```
def occurrences(text, sub):
    return len(re.findall('(?={0})'.format(re.escape(sub)), text))
```

```
>>> occurrences(text, '11')
5
```

Comment: Could you clarify why it would never be a problem? In practice, if there were a lot of matches or the matched substrings were very large, it could cause a lot of memory usage, no?

Comment: @wjandrea I think maybe I should have said "which would probably never be a problem" because I provided both the `iter` and non `iter` solution. But in this case the text is already in memory so I thought that getting the list would be fine

Answer (score 23):

You can also try using the [new Python regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), which supports overlapping matches.

```
import regex as re

def count_overlapping(text, search_for):
    return len(re.findall(search_for, text, overlapped=True))

count_overlapping('1011101111','11')  # 5
```

Comment: `import regex as re`? Isn't that confusing? Why not just `import regex`?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `import regex` -- documentation shows that approach. `regex`, however, has all the same components as the standard library `re`, so I prefer writing `re.compile`, etc. in way that is familiar and concise. Also, most of the time I end up using `regex` I started with `re` and then found some use case I want to rely on `regex`. I can then update `import re` to `import regex as re` at the top of the file and not have to make other changes.

Answer (score 15):

Python's `str.count` counts non-overlapping substrings:

```
In [3]: "ababa".count("aba")
Out[3]: 1
```

Here are a few ways to count overlapping sequences, I'm sure there are many more :)

#### Look-ahead regular expressions

[How to find overlapping matches with a regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430863/how-to-find-overlapping-matches-with-a-regexp)

```
In [10]: re.findall("a(?=ba)", "ababa")
Out[10]: ['a', 'a']
```

#### Generate all substrings

```
In [11]: data = "ababa"
In [17]: sum(1 for i in range(len(data)) if data.startswith("aba", i))
Out[17]: 2
```

Comment: More concise `sum(data.startswith("aba", i) for i, _ in enumerate(data))` :)

Answer (score 4):

```
s = "bobobob"
sub = "bob"
ln = len(sub)
print(sum(sub == s[i:i+ln] for i in xrange(len(s)-(ln-1))))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    count = 0
    for pos in range(len(string)):
        if string[pos:].startswith(sub_string):
            count += 1
    return count
```

This could be the easiest way.

Answer (score 4):

A fairly pythonic way would be to use list comprehension here, although it probably wouldn't be the most efficient.

```
sequence = 'abaaadcaaaa'
substr = 'aa'

counts = sum([
    sequence.startswith(substr, i) for i in range(len(sequence))
])
print(counts)  # 5
```

The list would be `[False, False, True, False, False, False, True, True, False, False]` as it checks all indexes through the string, and because `int(True) == 1`, `sum` gives us the total number of matches.

Answer (score 3):

## How to find a pattern in another string with overlapping

This function (another solution!) receive a pattern and a text. Returns a list with all the substring located in the and their positions.

```
def occurrences(pattern, text):
    """
    input: search a pattern (regular expression) in a text
    returns: a list of substrings and their positions 
    """
    p = re.compile('(?=({0}))'.format(pattern))
    matches = re.finditer(p, text)
    return [(match.group(1), match.start()) for match in matches]

print (occurrences('ana', 'banana'))
print (occurrences('.ana', 'Banana-fana fo-fana'))
```

> [('ana', 1), ('ana', 3)] 
> [('Bana', 0), ('nana', 2), ('fana', 7), ('fana', 15)]

Answer (score 2):

My answer, to the bob question on the course:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghaklbob'
total = 0
for i in range(len(s)-2):
    if s[i:i+3] == 'bob':
        total += 1
print 'number of times bob occurs is: ', total
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my edX MIT "find bob"* solution (*find number of "bob" occurences in a string named s), which basicaly counts overlapping occurrences of a given substing:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
count = 0

while 'bob' in s:
    count += 1 
    s = s[(s.find('bob') + 2):]

print "Number of times bob occurs is: {}".format(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative very close to the accepted answer but using `while` as the `if` test instead of including `if` inside the loop:

```
def countSubstr(string, sub):
    count = 0
    while sub in string:
        count += 1
        string = string[string.find(sub) + 1:]
    return count;
```

This avoids `while True:` and is a little cleaner in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

If strings are large, you want to use [Rabin-Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm), in summary:

- a rolling window of substring size, moving over a string
- a hash with O(1) overhead for adding and removing (i.e. move by 1 char)
- implemented in C or relying on pypy

Answer (score 1):

That can be solved using regex.

```
import re
def function(string, sub_string):
    match = re.findall('(?='+sub_string+')',string)
    return len(match)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i:].startswith(sub_string):
        counter = counter + 1
    return counter
```

Above code simply loops throughout the string once and keeps checking if any string is starting with the particular substring that is being counted.

Answer (score 1):

[`re.subn`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.subn) hasn't been mentioned yet:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.subn('(?=11)', '', '1011101111')[1]
5
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with replaced parts of the string

```py
s = 'lolololol'
t = 0
t += s.count('lol')
s = s.replace('lol', 'lo1')
t += s.count('1ol')
print("Number of times lol occurs is:", t)
```

Answer is 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_overlaps (string, look_for):
    start   = 0
    matches = 0

    while True:
        start = string.find (look_for, start)
        if start < 0:
            break

        start   += 1
        matches += 1

    return matches

print count_overlaps ('abrabra', 'abra')
```

Answer (score 0):

Function that takes as input two strings and counts how many times sub occurs in string, including overlaps. To check whether sub is a substring, I used the `in` operator.

```
def count_Occurrences(string, sub):
    count=0
    for i in range(0, len(string)-len(sub)+1):
        if sub in string[i:i+len(sub)]:
            count=count+1
    print 'Number of times sub occurs in string (including overlaps): ', count
```

Answer (score 0):

For a duplicated [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925123/python-3-count-the-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-a-string) i've decided to count it 3 by 3 and comparing the string e.g.

```
counted = 0

for i in range(len(string)):

    if string[i*3:(i+1)*3] == 'xox':
       counted = counted +1

print counted
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another example of using `str.find()` but a lot of the answers make it more complicated than necessary:

```
def occurrences(text, sub):
    c, n = 0, text.find(sub)
    while n != -1:
        c += 1
        n = text.find(sub, n+1)
    return c

In []:
occurrences('1011101111', '11')

Out[]:
5
```

Answer (score 0):

**Given**

```
sequence = '1011101111'
sub = "11"
```

**Code**

In this particular case:

```
sum(x == tuple(sub) for x in zip(sequence, sequence[1:]))
# 5
```

More generally, this

```
windows = zip(*([sequence[i:] for i, _ in enumerate(sequence)][:len(sub)]))
sum(x == tuple(sub) for x in windows)
# 5
```

or extend to generators:

```
import itertools as it


iter_ = (sequence[i:] for i, _ in enumerate(sequence))
windows = zip(*(it.islice(iter_, None, len(sub))))
sum(x == tuple(sub) for x in windows)
```

---

**Alternative**

You can use [`more_itertools.locate`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.locate):

```
import more_itertools as mit


len(list(mit.locate(sequence, pred=lambda *args: args == tuple(sub), window_size=len(sub))))
# 5
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to count substring occurrence is to use `count()`:

```
>>> s = 'bobob'
>>> s.count('bob')
1
```

You can use `replace ()` to find overlapping strings if you know which part will be overlap:

```
>>> s = 'bobob'
>>> s.replace('b', 'bb').count('bob')
2
```

Note that besides being static, there are other limitations:

```
>>> s = 'aaa'
>>> count('aa') # there must be two occurrences
1 
>>> s.replace('a', 'aa').count('aa')
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def occurance_of_pattern(text, pattern):
    text_len , pattern_len = len(text), len(pattern)
    return sum(1 for idx in range(text_len - pattern_len + 1) if text[idx: idx+pattern_len] == pattern)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to see if the number of input of same prefix char is same postfix, e.g., `"foo"` and `"""foo""` but fail on `"""bar""`:

````
from itertools import count, takewhile
from operator import eq


# From https://stackoverflow.com/a/15112059
def count_iter_items(iterable):
    """
    Consume an iterable not reading it into memory; return the number of items.

    :param iterable: An iterable
    :type iterable: ```Iterable```

    :return: Number of items in iterable
    :rtype: ```int```
    """
    counter = count()
    deque(zip(iterable, counter), maxlen=0)
    return next(counter)


def begin_matches_end(s):
    """
    Checks if the begin matches the end of the string

    :param s: Input string of length > 0
    :type s: ```str```

    :return: Whether the beginning matches the end (checks first match chars
    :rtype: ```bool```
    """
    return (count_iter_items(takewhile(partial(eq, s[0]), s)) ==
            count_iter_items(takewhile(partial(eq, s[0]), s[::-1])))
````

Answer (score -2):

If you want to count permutation counts of length 5 (adjust if wanted for different lengths):

```
def MerCount(s):
  for i in xrange(len(s)-4):
    d[s[i:i+5]] += 1
return d
```

Comment: 'count permutation counts' does not make much sense to me.  `d` is not a defined name.  If the code did run, it would not answer the question.