# Determing / Naming `Iterable`, `Sequence` and "infinite" `Iterable` in Python

Tags: python

I am aware that there are very good reasons not to force `__len__` to be part of the `iterator`s' API (e.g. [Understanding len function with iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728092/understanding-len-function-with-iterators#25731567)) and I do understand that the difference between an `Iterable` and a `Sequence` is mostly with the implementation of `__len__` (e.g. [What exactly does "iterable" mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799980/what-exactly-does-iterable-mean-in-python)).

However, I was wandering if there is a standard way of determining or at least naming "(in)finite" iterators, so that the need for avoiding infinite iterators is at least well-documented.

This would be useful if, for example, the code needs to iterate through all the elements of the `Iterable` and waiting for the system to run out of memory is not an acceptable behavior for the software.

Comment: I would simply never implement `__len__` if the iterator is infinite. If the iterator can be finite, you can implement `__len__` and raise a `ValueError` in case the iterator has infinite length. The `cycle` of `itertools` does this for instance: it does not implement `__len__`. As a result if `__len__` exists and returns a valid integer, it is guaranteed to be finite. After all, for some sequences it is currently not proven that they are finite.

Comment: For instance the Collatz conjecture defines a sequence, currently it is unknown if every element results in a finite sequence.

Comment: Deciding how to implement `__len__` is for when you are implementing your own `Sequence` or `Iterator`. You are right in that `cycle` does not implement `__len__`, but so does any `iterator` whether finite or infinite.
The question itself is whether there is a (standard) way of detecting/documenting failure/success for infinite iterators.