# Length of a finite generator

Tags: python, generator

I have these two implementations to compute the length of a finite generator, while keeping the data for further processing:

```
def count_generator1(generator):
    '''- build a list with the generator data
       - get the length of the data
       - return both the length and the original data (in a list)
       WARNING: the memory use is unbounded, and infinite generators will block this'''
    l = list(generator)
    return len(l), l

def count_generator2(generator):
    '''- get two generators from the original generator
       - get the length of the data from one of them
       - return both the length and the original data, as returned by tee
       WARNING: tee can use up an unbounded amount of memory, and infinite generators will block this'''
    for_length, saved  = itertools.tee(generator, 2)
    return sum(1 for _ in for_length), saved
```

Both have drawbacks, both do the job. Could somebody comment on them, or even offer a better alternative?

Comment: There is no way to know the length of an iterable generator without consuming the entire thing.

Comment: I know. That is not the question

Comment: note: if if you don't need the precise length then you could use [`operator.length_hint()` (Python 3.4+)](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/operator#operator.length_hint) that returns an estimated length without consuming the iterator. See [PEP 424 - A method for exposing a length hint](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0424/)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That's a nice addition for 3.4

Comment: Thanks, @J.F.Sebastian, but not clear if `length_hint` will consume the data or not. I assume not, otherwise, what is the point? Anyway, it is too magic for my taste.

Comment: @gonvaled: length_hint will call __length_hint__(), which is tricky to implement on a generator.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have to do this, the first method is much better - as you consume all the values, `itertools.tee()` will have to store all the values anyway, meaning a list will be more efficient.

To quote from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee):

> This itertool may require significant auxiliary storage (depending on
>   how much temporary data needs to be stored). In general, if one
>   iterator uses most or all of the data before another iterator starts,
>   it is faster to use list() instead of tee().

Comment: Well, in both cases I am consuming the generator, and storing the full data. In the first by creating a `list`, in the second just because `tee` has to do the same (or a similar thing). I think that getting the length of the list is faster (already part of the list object?), that is why I tend to prefer the first method. From the point of view of memory consumption, both seem equivalent, right?

Comment: @gonvaled Memory usage will probably be similar, but as I quote from the docs, making a list will be faster.

Answer (score 4):

I ran Windows 64-bit Python 3.4.3 `timeit` on a few approaches I could think of:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> from textwrap import dedent as d
>>> timeit(
...     d("""
...     count = -1
...     for _ in s:
...         count += 1
...     count += 1
...     """),
...     "s = range(1000)",
... )
50.70772041983173
>>> timeit(
...     d("""
...     count = -1
...     for count, _ in enumerate(s):
...         pass
...     count += 1
...     """),
...     "s = range(1000)",
... )
42.636973504498656
>>> timeit(
...     d("""
...     count, _ = reduce(f, enumerate(range(1000)), (-1, -1))
...     count += 1
...     """),
...     d("""
...     from functools import reduce
...     def f(_, count):
...         return count
...     s = range(1000)
...     """),
... )
121.15513102540672
>>> timeit("count = sum(1 for _ in s)", "s = range(1000)")
58.179126025925825
>>> timeit("count = len(tuple(s))", "s = range(1000)")
19.777029680237774
>>> timeit("count = len(list(s))", "s = range(1000)")
18.145157531932
>>> timeit("count = len(list(1 for _ in s))", "s = range(1000)")
57.41422175998332
```

Shockingly, the fastest approach was to use a `list` (not even a `tuple`) to exhaust the iterator and get the length from there:

```
>>> timeit("count = len(list(s))", "s = range(1000)")
18.145157531932
```

Of course, this risks memory issues.  The best low-memory alternative was to use enumerate on a NOOP `for`-loop:

```
>>> timeit(
...     d("""
...     count = -1
...     for count, _ in enumerate(s):
...         pass
...     count += 1
...     """),
...     "s = range(1000)",
... )
42.636973504498656
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the length of the iterator prior to processing the data, you could use a helper method with a future to add in counting into the processing of your iterator/stream:

```
import asyncio
def ilen(iter):
    """
    Get future with length of iterator
    The future will hold the length once the iteartor is exhausted
    @returns: <iter, cnt-future>
    """
    def ilen_inner(iter, future):
        cnt = 0
        for row in iter:
            cnt += 1
            yield row
        future.set_result(cnt)
    cnt_future = asyncio.Future()
    return ilen_inner(iter, cnt_future), cnt_future
```

Usage would be:

```
data = db_connection.execute(query)
data, cnt = ilen(data)
solve_world_hunger(data)
print(f"Processed {cnt.result()} items")
```