# Python 2 --> 3: object of type 'zip' has no len()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm following a tutorial on neural nets[1](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html)

It's in Python 2.7. I'm using 3.4. This is the line that troubles me:

`if test_data: n_test = len(test_data)`

I get: `TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len()`.

Is there a way to rewrite it so that it works in 3.4?

Comment: related: [Length of a finite generator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18014437/4279)

Comment: related: [Getting number of elements in an iterator in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3345785/4279)

Comment: If you have access to the two iterables that have been zipped, just compute the length of both and take whichever is smaller. The length of the zip is not going to be any different from that.

Comment: Try using `list(zip(...)` where you have `zip(...)`

Comment: That appears to have fixed it, although I get a second error in regards to `mini_batches = [training_data[k:k+mini_batch_size] for k in range(0, n, mini_batch_size)]` the error reads `File "/home/lukasz/Documents/Machine Learning/network.py", line 66, in <listcomp> for k in range(0, n, mini_batch_size)] TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable
` w

Comment: same problem, the program is trying to do something like `zip(...)[i]`. Best would be to define a new variable `new_var = list(zip(...))` and replacing `zip(...)` with `new_var`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you know that the iterator is finite:

```
#NOTE: `sum()` consumes the iterator
n_test = sum(1 for _ in test_data) # find len(iterator)
```

Or if you know that `test_data` is always small *and* a profiler says that the code is the bottleneck in your application then here's code that might be more efficient for small `n_test`:

```
test_data = list(test_data)
n_test = len(test_data)
```

Unfortunately, [`operator.length_hint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.length_hint) (Python 3.4+) returns zero for a `zip()` object. See [PEP 0424 -- A method for exposing a length hint](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0424/).

Comment: You should do `test_data = list(test_data)` before the `if` check, otherwise `if test_data` will always be true, even for an empty `zip`. Also might be worth pointing out that `sum(...)` will consume the `zip`

Comment: I see you point... in fact, the `if` check would not be needed if it were just an empty list (then `n_test` would just be 0). Still, might be worth pointing out, just in case.

Comment: Working through your suggestions now, thanks a lot. It's someone else's code and I admit it's stretching my ability. Cheers!

Answer (score 66):

A bit late now to answer, but in case anyone else stumbles on it: for that same neural net example tutorial, it turned out I had to wrap the 3 zip calls in the mnist_loader with a list(zip(...)) construct:

```
training_data = list(zip(training_inputs, training_results))
(...)
validation_data = list(zip(validation_inputs, va_d[1]))
(...)
test_data = list(zip(test_inputs, te_d[1]))
```

And then it worked.

Comment: late but welcome for those who arrive even later, ty

Comment: All three in `load_data_wrapper()`.

Comment: they are talking about this tutorial: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html

Answer (score 13):

Force the `zip()` to evaluate.

```
foo = list(zip(...))
```

Answer (score 3):

## Some Info

This is because in the Python 3.x, `zip` returns a generator object. This object is not a list (it's better) but it behaves like one. You can try iterating through it like this:

```
for i in zip([1,2,3,4], ['a','b','c','d']):
    print i
```

## The Quick Answer

Please show us the code surrounding where the error happened.
But I think I can still give you a quick (and not necessarily good) solution.

turn this

```
for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
```

into this:

```
for i in reversed(range(1, len(list(x))):
```

Comment: Even better for performance is if you can keep using generators, so that you do not build huge lists in memory. This will probably require more thorough refactoring, which is not possible with the code fragments in the question alone.

Comment: FYI: merged from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045628/error-while-shuffling-data-for-neural-network

Answer (score 2):

In mnist_loader wrap your zip results in `list()` constructs like below

```
def load_data_wrapper():    
    tr_d, va_d, te_d = load_data()
    training_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784,1)) for x in tr_d[0]]
    training_results = [vectorized_result(y) for y in tr_d[1]]
    training_data = list(zip(training_inputs, training_results))
    validation_inputs = [np.reshape(x,(784, 1))for x in va_d[0]]
    validation_data = list(zip(validation_inputs, va_d[1]))
    test_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in te_d[0]]
    test_data = list(zip(test_inputs, te_d[1]))
    return(training_data, validation_data, test_data)
```

Comment: This looks like the better choice, as it fixes the problem right where it is originated with the use of zip()