# Count number of elements in a iterable

Tags: python, count, iterator, iterable

What's the best way of counting the number of elements in a iterable (through iteration), without storing the elements in memory?

Right now, I'm just doing `sum(1 for x in iterable)`. I was hoping to find something in `itertools`, but there doesn't seem to be anything.

Comment: As a sidenote, this feature has been requested years back: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2003-August/182237.html, but unfortunately the discussion stopped there, I think this question comes up so often it should be added to python.

Answer (score 5):

`sum(1 for x in iterable)` *is* the best method. Not everything requires a dedicated `itertools` function. :-) I note that the top-voted answer on the [post you claim not to be a dupe of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3345807) also advices you to use this.

Of course, it is always valuable to look at `itertools` just in case, and if you do, don't forget to check the [recipes section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes); you'll find the `quantify()` recipe which does pretty much the same thing, but with a predicate to filter the iterable:

```
def quantify(iterable, pred=bool):
    "Count how many times the predicate is true"
    return sum(imap(pred, iterable))
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO this feature should be included in itertools, but is not.

[more-itertools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/more-itertools/2.2) is a package which includes `ilen`, but could be a little heavy-weight for your situation. When I encounter this I just define your commonly used workaround as `ilen`:

```
def ilen(iterable):
    return sum(1 for _ in iterable)
```

Comment: I don't think there is much value in taking the *basic building blocks* that `itertools` provide and wrapping something as simple as that one-liner into a function. Because the `ilen()` function in `more-itertools` does exactly what you included in your answer here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It can be useful if it's used often enough, as the `sum` workaround doesn't feel that clean to me.

Comment: `more-itertools` seems to include lots of useful methods, I wish I had known about it sooner!

Comment: @simonzack note that [you're using the `sum` workaround](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools/blob/master/more_itertools/more.py#L203) when you use `ilen`, which is what Martijn Pieters was referring to, I think. `ilen` makes your intention much more clear, though.