# Fastest way to count list values below a threshold

Tags: python, performance, list, count

Is there list method equivalent to numpy.count_nonzero(lst < t)?
when I use it on list (lst < t) just returns True instead of list of booleans.
I want to count list values below some threshold
what is better - converting to numpy-array, using sort, some kind of list/generator comprehension or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorting is not recommended as it is O(N*logN), where all other soloutions are simply O(N).

You can use a generator expression and a [generator-len](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3345807/2096752) function, like this:

```
n = iterlen( x for x in lst if x < t )
```

This is better than list-comprehension becuase you don't need to construct the temporary list (of which you take the len), which takes up both time and memory.

Depending on the details of the problem (list size, element type), converting to a numpy array might prove faster. You should time both approaches, and see which one works best in your case.

Of course, the best solution, if possible, would be to represent the list as a numpy array to begin with.  If you do that, `numpy.count_nonzero(lst < t)` is almost certain to be fastest.

Or, if you can build a sorted list to begin with, you can easily implement a `count_less` function using [`bisect`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3345807/2096752). The complexity here is O(logN), which would be the fastest for large lists.

Answer (score 2):

c will be the count of all items in a list (lst) that are below value t:

```
c = len([i for i in lst if i < t])
```

Comment: What if `lst` is 4GB?

Comment: Then go with the other guy's answer. I even up-voted it. BTW, this will still work on 4 gigs; it'll just be slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [cardinality](http://cardinality.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package for this:

Usage:

```
>>> import cardinality
>>> cardinality.count(i for i in range(500) if i > 499)
1
```

The actual count() implementation is as follows:

```
def count(iterable):
    if hasattr(iterable, '__len__'):
        return len(iterable)

    d = collections.deque(enumerate(iterable, 1), maxlen=1)
    return d[0][0] if d else 0
```