# Why CPython call len(iterable) when executing func(*iterable)?

Tags: python, cpython

Recently I'm writing a download program, which uses the HTTP Range field to download many blocks at the same time. I wrote a Python class to represent the Range (the HTTP header's Range is a closed interval):

```
class ClosedRange:
    def __init__(self, begin, end):
        self.begin = begin
        self.end = end

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.begin
        yield self.end

    def __str__(self):
        return '[{0.begin}, {0.end}]'.format(self)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.end - self.begin + 1
```

The `__iter__` magic method is to support the tuple unpacking:

```
header = {'Range': 'bytes={}-{}'.format(*the_range)}
```

And `len(the_range)` is how many bytes in that Range.

Now I found that `'bytes={}-{}'.format(*the_range)` occasionally causes the `MemoryError`. After some debugging I found that the CPython interpreter will try to call `len(iterable)` when executing `func(*iterable)`, and (may) allocate memory based on the length. On my machine, when `len(the_range)` is greater than 1GB, the `MemoryError` appears.

This is a simplified one:

```
class C:
    def __iter__(self):
        yield 5

    def __len__(self):
        print('__len__ called')
        return 1024**3

def f(*args):
    return args

>>> c = C()
>>> f(*c)
__len__ called
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
>>> # BTW, `list(the_range)` have the same problem.
>>> list(c)
__len__ called
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

So my questions are:

1. Why CPython call `len(iterable)`? From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345785/getting-number-of-elements-in-an-iterator-in-python) I see you won't know an iterator's length until you iterate throw it. Is this an optimization?
2. Can `__len__` method return the 'fake' length (i.e. not the real number of elements in memory) of an object?

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0424/. I would recommend not doing this (having an `__iter__` that doesn’t yield the elements of a range) anyway.

Comment: If your iterator yields two items, then the length of your sequence is two.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga @Ryan I know it. `list(it)` or `f(*it)` both create a sequence, and will call `operator.length_hint(it)` to pre-allocate space. And `operator.length_hint` see that `it` has `__len__` method, so just returns `len(it)` -- the sequence so allocates too large. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why CPython call `len(iterable)`? From this question I see you won't know an iterator's length until you iterate throw it. Is this an optimization?

when python (assuming python3) execute `f(*c)`, opcode `CALL_FUNCTION_EX` is used:

```
 0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (f)
 2 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (c)
 4 CALL_FUNCTION_EX         0
 6 POP_TOP
```

as `c` is an iterable, `PySequence_Tuple` is called to convert it to a tuple, then `PyObject_LengthHint` is called to determine the new tuple length, as `__len__` method is defined on `c`, it gets called and its return value is used to allocate memory for a new tuple, as `malloc` failed, finally `MemoryError` error gets raised.

```
/* Guess result size and allocate space. */
n = PyObject_LengthHint(v, 10);
if (n == -1)
    goto Fail;
result = PyTuple_New(n);
```

> Can `__len__` method return the 'fake' length (i.e. not the real number of elements in memory) of an object?

in this scenario, yes.

when the return value of `__len__` is smaller than need, python will adjust memory space of new tuple object to fit when filling the tuple. if it is larger than need, although python will allocate extra memory, `_PyTuple_Resize` will be called in the end to reclaim over-allocated space.