# Tensorflow: How to find the size of a tf.data.Dataset API object

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I understand Dataset API is a sort of a iterator which does not load the entire dataset into memory, because of which it is unable to find the size of the Dataset. I am talking in the context of large corpus of data that is stored in text files or tfRecord files. These files are generally read using `tf.data.TextLineDataset` or something similar. It is trivial to find the size of dataset loaded using `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`.

The reason I am asking the size of the Dataset is the following:
Let's say my Dataset size is 1000 elements. Batch size = 50 elements. Then training steps/batches (assuming 1 epoch) = 20. During these 20 steps, I would like to exponentially decay my learning rate from 0.1 to 0.01 as

```
tf.train.exponential_decay(
    learning_rate = 0.1,
    global_step = global_step,
    decay_steps = 20,
    decay_rate = 0.1,
    staircase=False,
    name=None
)
```

In the above code, I have "and" would like to set `decay_steps = number of steps/batches per epoch = num_elements/batch_size`. This can be calculated only if the number of elements in the dataset is known in advance.

Another reason to know the size in advance is to split the data into train and test sets using `tf.data.Dataset.take()`, `tf.data.Dataset.skip()` methods.

PS: I am not looking for brute-force approaches like iterating through the whole dataset and updating a counter to count the number of elements or [putting a very large batch size and then finding the size of the resultant dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48126690/how-to-make-tf-data-dataset-return-all-of-the-elements-in-one-call), etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily get the number of data samples using :

```
dataset.__len__()
```

You can get each element like this:

```
for step, element in enumerate(dataset.as_numpy_iterator()):
...     print(step, element)
```

You can also get the shape of one sample:

```
dataset.element_spec
```

If you want to take specific elements you can use shard method as well.

Comment: `dataset.__len__()` does not work for a dataset made with `tf.data.TextLineDataset`. Error is `TypeError: dataset length is unknown.`

Comment: I found that TextLineDataset reads each file and takes each row of that files as samples, so what you can do is len(dataset.as_numpy_iterator()). However, number of characters for each row varies, Then you can use some fixed size to make it trainable.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is two years old, but perhaps this answer will be useful.

If you are reading your data with `tf.data.TextLineDataset`, then a way to get the number of samples could be to count the number of lines in all of the text files you are using.

Consider the following example:

```
import random
import string
import tensorflow as tf

filenames = ["data0.txt", "data1.txt", "data2.txt"]

# Generate synthetic data.
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        lines = [random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(random.randint(10, 100))]
        print("\n".join(lines), file=f)

dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(filenames)
```

Trying to get the length with `len` raises a `TypeError`:

```
len(dataset)
```

But one can calculate the number of lines in a file relatively quickly.

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/q/845058/5666087
def get_n_lines(filepath):
    i = -1
    with open(filepath) as f:
        for i, _ in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

n_lines = sum(get_n_lines(f) for f in filenames)
```

In the above, `n_lines` is equal to the number of elements found when iterating over the dataset with

```
for i, _ in enumerate(dataset):
    pass
n_lines == i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it an option for you to specify the size of your dataset by hand?

How I load my data:

```
sample_id_hldr = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int64, shape=(None,), name="samples")

sample_ids = tf.Variable(sample_id_hldr, validate_shape=False, name="samples_cache")
num_samples = tf.size(sample_ids)

data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(sample_ids)
# "load" data by id:
# return (id, data) for each id
data = data.map(
    lambda id: (id, some_load_op(id))
)
```

Here you can specify all your sample id's by initializing `sample_ids` once with the placeholder.
Your sample id's could be e.g. file paths or simple numbers (`np.arange(num_elems)`)

The number of elements is then available in `num_samples`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. However it seems you did not get my question, sorry for that. I will revise my question again. I am not using `from_tensor_slices` which is used when you have small datasets. In that case, it is trivial to find the size of the dataset. My question is about reading large corpus of data stored in text files that can be only read using `tf.data.TextLineDataset()`. In this case, how to find the size of the entire dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Here what I did to solve the problem, add the following line to your dataset `tf.data.experimental.assert_cardinality(len_of_data)` this will fix the problem,

```
ast = Audioset(df) # the generator class
db = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(ast, output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.int32))
db = db.apply(tf.data.experimental.assert_cardinality(len(ast))) # number of samples
db = db.batch(batch_size)
```

the dataset len change based on the batch_size, to get the dataset len just run `len(db)`.
check [here](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/creating-dataset-from-tensorflow-imagedatagenerator-31ce5706612b) for more details