# Is there a way in Python to have the following output?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

By using Python (mostly REGEX), I would like to have the following output:

```
string = 'leelee'
result = [('l',1),('e',2),('l',1),('e',2)]
```

Comment: Regex finds/searches, not creates new output

Comment: 'string' is your desired output or 'result' ?

Comment: result is required output

Comment: The answer to "is it possible" is usually "yes" -- you're using a general-purpose language on a general-purpose computer, so you have full Turing potential.  The implied question behind this, "how do I do it?" is an open-ended, individualized tutorial, which is *seriously* off-topic for Stack Overflow -- please re-take the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Just loop over the string and count the number of occurrences.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with regex plus other tools, but it's not ideal. Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is much easier.

```
from itertools import groupby
result = [(k, sum(1 for _ in g)) for k, g in groupby(string)]
```

This method of getting the len of an iterator is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3345807/4518341).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the *help* of regex, but not regex alone.

First group by character, then list comprehension to count elements in those groups.

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##DccxDoAgDADAnVd0o1VjJM6@BBlMrJEEC6kM@no0ueXKW88sc2vxKlkrKJsbFrCJ@WfN80d5PKLsW0qoFkfC1XVkh5tM0SgVvWc/hcH1iQXZu0ABjqzAEAWeQK19)

```
import re
s = 'leelee'
x = re.findall(r'(.)(\1*)',s)
print([[e[0],1+len(e[1])] for e in x])
```

The regex above captures a character `(.)`, then matches that character any number of times if it immediately follows it `(\1*)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need regex? Python's `*` is string multiplication, and `+` is string concatenation. For example:

```
print("h" * 5) # hhhhh
print("h" + "t") # ht
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version with a bunch of `for` loops:

```
for pair in result:
    for char, times in pair:
        for _ in range(times):
            print(char, end='')
```

Or here's one with comprehension and `join`:

```
print(''.join([x * y for x, y in result]))
```

Or the most direct solution:

```
print(string)
```

I don't think you'll find one that just uses regexes though...

Comment: I have string as a input and want result as an output.