# Can't get my count function to work in Python

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a function where you can put in a phrase such as "ana" in the word "banana", and count how many times it finds the phrase in the word. I can't find the error I'm making for some of my test units not to work.

```
def test(actual, expected):
    """ Compare the actual to the expected value,
        and print a suitable message.
    """
    import sys
    linenum = sys._getframe(1).f_lineno   # get the caller's line number.
    if (expected == actual):
        msg = "Test on line {0} passed.".format(linenum)
    else:
        msg = ("Test on line {0} failed. Expected '{1}', but got '{2}'.".format(linenum, expected, actual))
    print(msg)

def count(phrase, word):
    count1 = 0
    num_phrase = len(phrase)   
    num_letters = len(word)    

    for i in range(num_letters):
        for x in word[i:i+num_phrase]:
             if phrase in word:
                 count1 += 1
             else:
                 continue    
        return count1

def test_suite():
    test(count('is', 'Mississippi'), 2)
    test(count('an', 'banana'), 2)
    test(count('ana', 'banana'), 2)
    test(count('nana', 'banana'), 1)
    test(count('nanan', 'banana'), 0)
    test(count('aaa', 'aaaaaa'), 4)

test_suite()
```

Comment: What are the errors? P.S. please reduce the excess empty lines, to make your question more readable. Thank you.

Comment: Your iteration for x in word[] does not make sense to me.

Comment: Your variable names are very confusing. For example `num_phrase` is not the number of a phrase, but its *length.* `x` is *completely* non-descriptive. In my experience, sorting out the terminology tends to reveal problems in short order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing your `count` function to the following passes the tests:

```
def count(phrase, word):
    count1 = 0
    num_phrase = len(phrase)   
    num_letters = len(word)    
    for i in range(num_letters):
        if word[i:i+num_phrase] == phrase:
          count1 += 1
    return count1
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I overlooked that. I guess I just make my function too complicated.

Comment: If you're searching for and/or in large strings there are several [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) to speed up the search.

Answer (score 4):

Use `str.count(substring)`. This will return how many times the substring occurs in the full string (`str`).

Here is an interactive session showing how it works:

```
>>> 'Mississippi'.count('is')
2
>>> 'banana'.count('an')
2
>>> 'banana'.count('ana')
1
>>> 'banana'.count('nana')
1
>>> 'banana'.count('nanan')
0
>>> 'aaaaaa'.count('aaa')
2
>>>
```

As you can see, the function is **non-overlapping**. If you need overlapping behaviour, look here: [string count with overlapping occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970520/string-count-with-overlapping-occurances)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the iteration wrong, so:

```
for i in range(num_letters):   #This will go from 1, 2, ---> len(word)    

    for x in word[i:i+num_phrase]:  
    #This will give you the letters starting from word[i] to [i_num_phrase] 
    #but one by one, so :  for i in 'dada': will give you 'd' 'a' 'd' 'a'

         if phrase in word:       #This condition doesnt make sense in your problem, 
                                  #if it's true it will hold true trough all the 
                                  #iteration and count will be 
                                  #len(word) * num_phrase,                 
                                  #and if it's false it will return 0
             count1 += 1
         else:
             continue
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, str.count(substring) is wrong solution, because it doesn't count overlapping substrings and test suite fails.

There is also builtin [str.find](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.find#str.find) method, which could be helpful for the task.

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

def count(sequence,item) :

```
  count = 0

  for x in sequence :

     if x == item :
     count = count+1
  return count
```

Answer (score -1):

A basic question rais this times.

when u see a string like `"isisisisisi"` howmany "isi" do u count?

at first state you see the string `"isi s isi s isi"` and return 3 as count.

at the second state you see the string `"isisisisisi"` and counts the "i" tow times per phrase like this `"isi isi isi isi isi"`.
In other word second 'i' is last character of first 'isi' and first character of second 'isi'.

so you have to return 5 as count.

for first state simply can use:

```
>>> string = "isisisisisi"
>>> string.count("isi")
3
```

and for second state you have to recognize the `"phrase"+"anything"+"phrase"` in the search keyword.

the below function can do it:

```
def find_iterate(Str):
     i = 1
     cnt = 0
     while Str[i-1] == Str[-i] and i < len(Str)/2:
         i += 1
         cnt += 1
     return Str[0:cnt+1]
```

Now you have many choice to count the search keyword in the string.

for example I do such below:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    search_keyword = "isi"
    String = "isisisisisi"
    itterated_part = find_iterate(search_keyword)
    c = 0
    while search_keyword in String:
        c += String.count(search_keyword)
        String = String.replace(search_keyword, itterated_part)
    print c
```

I do not know if a better way be in python.but I tried to do this with help of Regular Expressions but found no way.