# Python: how to count overlapping occurrences of a substring

Tags: python

I wanted to count the number of times that a string like 'aa' appears in 'aaa' (or 'aaaa').

The most obvious code gives the wrong (or at least, not the intuitive) answer:

```
'aaa'.count('aa')
1 # should be 2
'aaaa'.count('aa')
2 # should be 3
```

Does anyone have a simple way to fix this?

Comment: Or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970520/string-count-with-overlapping-occurances

Answer (score 10):

From [`str.count()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) documentation:

> Return the number of **non-overlapping occurrences** of substring sub in the range [start, end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

So, no. You are getting the expected result.

If you want to count number of overlapping matches, use `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> len(re.findall(r'(a)(?=\1)', 'aaa'))
2
```

This finds all the occurrence of `a`, which is followed by `a`. The 2nd `a` wouldn't be captured, as we've used look-ahead, which is zero-width assertion.

Comment: Well, yes. But the question is how to calculate it instead?

Comment: I mean, you're 100% correct. But that's not helpful :/

Comment: You can instead change your OP to 'how to count overlapping occurrences of a substring', to emphasize that you want to know HOW, rather than why it is giving an answer that is not intuitive to you.

Answer (score 6):

```
haystack = "aaaa"
needle   = "aa"

matches  = sum(haystack[i:i+len(needle)] == needle 
               for i in xrange(len(haystack)-len(needle)+1))

# for Python 3 use range instead of xrange
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I'll use this since I'm not familiar with regex

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not taking overlap into consideration.

Try this:

```
big_string = "aaaa"
substring = "aaa"
count = 0 

for char in range(len(big_string)):
    count += big_string[char: char + len(subtring)] == substring

print count
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful, because you seem to looking for non-overlapping substrings. To fix this I'd do:

```
len([s.start() for s in re.finditer('(?=aa)', 'aaa')])
```

And if you don't care about the position where the substring starts you can do:

```
len([_ for s in re.finditer('(?=aa)', 'aaa')])
```

Although someone smarter than myself might be able to show that there are performances differences :)