# python pattern count Find a “hidden message” in the replication origin

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

The question ask to find a “hidden message” in the replication origin.

```
Input: A string Text (representing the replication origin of a genome).

Output: A hidden message in Text.
```

Translate to computational language,

```
Input: Strings Text and Pattern.

Output: Count(Text, Pattern).
```

For example,

```
Count(ACAACTATGCATACTATCGGGAACTATCCT, ACTAT) = 3.
```

In theory, we should account for overlapping occurrences of Pattern in Text right? So one way to do it is to screen down from first element to the length of text-length of the pattern we are looking for?

Here's the pseudo code i come up with,

```
def PatternCount(Text, Pattern):
    count = 0
    for i = 0 to len(Text)-len(Pattern):
        if Text(i, len(Pattern)) = Pattern:
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

Any suggestion? I'm new to python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find the number of overlapping sequences in a String with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844005/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-overlapping-sequences-in-a-string-with-python)

Comment: A similar question and answer (if you want non-overlapping) can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566503/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-word-in-a-string

Comment: @tvandenbrande it seems that the OP wants to count all overlapping sequences.

Comment: OP, have a look to the possible duplicate and to https://stackoverflow.com/q/19302525

Comment: how about re.findall(pattern, text)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```
def pattern_count(text, pattern):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, len(text) - len(pattern) + 1):
        if text[i : len(pattern) + i] == pattern:
            count += 1
    return count
```

We're using string slicing (`text[i : len(pattern) + i]`) to check if the sub-string matches the pattern.

Input: `text = "abc123!@#654abcabc"` and `pattern = "abc"`
Output: `3`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
print len(re.findall("abc", "abc123!@#654abcabc"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a more "pythonic" solution would be to use list comprehensions.

```
def pattern_count(text, pattern):
    return len([x for x in range(len(text) - len(pattern)+1) if pattern in text[x:len(pattern)+x]])
```