# python re.findall() with list

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, findall

I have a long string (e.g. AAAABBBBCCCC) and I eventually want to find all overlapping occurrences for each member of a list of different substrings (e.g. ['AAA', 'AAB', 'ABB', 'BBB']).

I found a very helpful suggestion on a previous StackOverflow posting -  [string count with overlapping occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970520/string-count-with-overlapping-occurances) However, using this I can't seem to assign the substrings in such a way that re.findall() can recognize them. It's probably something stupid, but I just can't seem to figure it out. It seems like the `?` is doing something different than usual...

```
>>> string = 'AAAABBBBCCCC'
>>> len(re.findall('(?=AAA)', string))
2
>>> substring = 'AAA'
>>> len(re.findall('(?=substring)', string))
0
>>> substring = "'(?=AAA)'"
>>> len(re.findall(substring, string))
0
>>> #This works, but is not overlapping:
>>> substring = 'AAA'
>>> len(re.findall(substring, string))
1
```

I would appreciate any suggestions! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to assign a variable and use it in the `findall` function?

```
>>> substring = '(?=AAA)' #or "(?=AAA)"
>>> len(re.findall(substring, string))
>>> 2
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Duh! I guess I didn't need the second quotes because it was already considered a string : ) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you with the rest, your 5th line is string substring not variable sub string.

```
import re
string = 'AAAABBBBCCCC'
len(re.findall('(?=AAA)', string))
2
substring = 'AAA'
len(re.findall('(?=' + substring + ')', string))
2
```