# Does Python have a string contains how many substring method, allowing for overlap?

Tags: string, python-2.7

I want to count a long string contain how many substring, how to do it in python?

```
"12212"
```

contains 2x `"12"`

how to get the count number?

It must allow for overlaping substrings; for instance "1111" contains 3 `"11"` substrings.

`"12121"` contains 2 `"121"` substrings.

```
"1111".count("11")
```

will return 2. It does not count any overlaps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1155647/16139

Comment: The important question is how you want to handle overlapping matches: `"121212".count("1212") == 1`, which might not be what you want.

Comment: In case you want to count overlapping substrings, you could use this: `count_all = lambda string, sub: sum(string[i:i+len(sub)] == sub for i in range(len(string) - len(sub) + 1))`

Comment: @Martijn Sorry, but I add some more detail information about can contain overlap and repeat.

Comment: Now it is a duplicate of [string count with overlapping occurances](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2970520)

Comment: possible duplicate of [string count with overlapping occurances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970520/string-count-with-overlapping-occurances)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings have a method count

You can do

```
s = '12212'

s.count('12') # this equals 2
```

Edited for the changing question, the answer below was posted as a comment by tobias_k

To count with overlap,

```
count_all = lambda string, sub: sum(string[i:i+len(sub)] == sub for i in range(len(string) - len(sub) + 1))
```

This can be called with,

```
count_all('1111', '11') # this returns 3
```

Comment: I need it can repeat and can overlap