# Overlapping count of substring in a string in Python

Tags: python, string, count, substring

I want to find all the counts (overlapping and non-overlapping) of a sub-string in a string. 
I found two answers one of which is using regex which is not my intention and the other was much more in-efficient than I need.
I need something like:

```
'ababaa'.count('aba') == 2
```

`str.count()` just counts simple substrings. What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String count with overlapping occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970520/string-count-with-overlapping-occurrences)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def sliding(a, n):
    return (a[i:i+n] for i in xrange(len(a) - n + 1))

def substring_count(a, b):
    return sum(s == b for s in sliding(a, len(b)))

assert list(sliding('abcde', 3)) == ['abc', 'bcd', 'cde']    
assert substring_count('ababaa', 'aba') == 2
```

Comment: what would be time complexity?

Comment: For fixed |b|, it's O(|a|). As a function of both |a| and |b|, I'd have to think more... probably O(|a| * |b|). Might be able to give a better bound, but I'm guessing you only care about the situation where |b| << |a| ?

Comment: Well, it's much efficient. Thanks @ChrisMartin

Answer (score 2):

```
count = len(set([string.find('aba',x) for x in range(len(string)) if string.find('aba',x) >= 0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this do the trick?

```
def count(string, substring):
    n = len(substring)
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(len(string) - n):
        if string[i:i+n] == substring:
            cnt += 1
    return cnt

print count('ababaa', 'aba') # 2
```

I don't know if there's a more efficient solution, but this should work.

Comment: It does, but it's efficiency is what matters. If the iteration was all I had to do, I could have done it, in fact, I've done it but I need less time consuming because the problem I'm solving consists of very large strings, where I don't think iteration would work.

Comment: @lavee_singh This is essentially the same algorithm as mine, just written in a procedural rather than functional style. Same complexity.

Comment: Sorry, but there is difference, a lot of it. You are using by creating lists and iterators, which is essentially slower than generators. Try to mark the difference in () and [], this is a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

Here, using [re.finditer()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) is the best way to achieve what you want.

```
import re 

def get_substring_count(s, sub_s):
    return sum(1 for m in re.finditer('(?=%s)' % sub_s, s))

get_substring_count('ababaa', 'aba')
# 2 as response
```

Comment: what would be the time complexity?

Comment: It's good, but I've got a solution with better time complexity. But this is really good as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function you could use:

```
def count(haystack, needle):
    return len([x for x in [haystack[i:j+1] for i in xrange(len(haystack)) for j in xrange(i,len(haystack))] if x == needle])
```

Then:

```
>>> count("ababaa", "aba")
2
```

Answer (score 1):

A brute-force approach is just

```
n = len(needle)
count = sum(haystack[i:i+n] == needle for i in range(len(haystack)-n+1))
```

(this works because in Python `True` and `False` are equivalent to numbers `1` and `0` for most uses, including math).

Using a regexp instead it could be

```
count = len(re.findall(needle[:1]+"(?="+re.escape(needle[1:])+")",
                       haystack))
```

(i.e. using `a(?=ba)` instead of `aba` to find overlapping matches too)

Answer (score 1):

Looping through sliced string

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    l = len(sub_string)
    n = len(string)
    count = sum(1 for i in range(n-l+1) if string[i:i+l].count(sub_string)>0 )
    return count
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to consider is by leveraging the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) container. While the accepted answer is fastest for shorter strings, if you are searching relatively short substrings within long strings the Counter approach starts to take the edge. Also, if you have need to refactor this to perform multiple substring count queries against the same main string, then the Counter approach starts looking much more attractive

For example, searching for a substring of length = 3 gave me the following results using timeit;

Main string length / Accepted Answer / Counter Approach

6 characters / 4.1us / 7.4us

50 characters / 24.4us / 25us

150 characters / 70.7us / 64.9us

1500 characters / 723us / 614us

```
from collections import Counter

def count_w_overlap(search_string, main_string):
    #Split up main_string into all possible overlap possibilities
    search_len = len(search_string)
    candidates = [main_string[i:i+search_len] for i in range(0, len(main_string) - search_len + 1)]
    #Create the Counter container
    freq_count = Counter(candidates)
    return freq_count[search_string]
```