# Any way to count overlapped strings within another string?

Tags: python, string, count, overlap

What is the simple way to count the indexes(locations) of overlap characters identically between two string?

```
def overlap(string1, string2):

    count = 0

    for i in range(0,len(string1)-len(string2)+1):
        if string2 in string1[i:i+len(string2)]:
            count = count +1
    return count
```

I realize I have some issues with my function. Could someone please point out and explain? That would be so helpful!

sample:

```
overlap('abcb','dbeb') #output >>> 2, not 4
overlap('','winter')   #output >>> 0.
```

Comment: oh yes, thanks for advice

Comment: What is your current code's output, what would be the expected output? Are you looking for the same thing as question [Overlapping count of substring in a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283255/overlapping-count-of-substring-in-a-string-in-python), maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the strings can have different lengths, use the minimum length.  Then compare them using array indexes, character by character.  Conceptually:

```
def overlap(string1, string2):
  count=0
  for i in range(min(len(string1),len(string2))):
    if string1[i] == string2[i]:
      count += 1
  return count
```

You could implement it with the `zip` built-in function (look at python documentation).

Comment: Thanks for help and explanation. I think I understand it now. Wasn't thought about the minimum length. ;)