# Count multiple letters in string Python

Tags: python, string, count

I'm trying to count the letter's 'l' and 'o' in the string below. 
It seems to work if i count one letter, but as soon as i count the next letter 'o' the string does not add to the total count. What am I missing?

```
s = "hello world"

print s.count('l' and 'o')
```

> Output: 5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably mean `s.count('l') + s.count('o')`.

The code you've pasted is equal to `s.count('o')`: the `and` operator checks if its first operand (in this case `l`) is false. If it is false, it returns its first operand (`l`), but it isn't, so it returns the second operand (`o`).

```
>>> True and True
True
>>> True and False
False
>>> False and True
False
>>> True and 'x'
'x'
>>> False and 'x'
False
>>> 'x' and True
True
>>> 'x' and False
False
>>> 'x' and 'y'
'y'
>>> 'l' and 'o'
'o'
>>> s.count('l' and 'o')
2
>>> s.count('o')
2
>>> s.count('l') + s.count('o')
5
```

[Official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

Comment: @taji01That's a whole different question, especially because you seem to be looking for *overlapping* matches. `count` counts non-overlapping matches. [See here.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2970520/182402)

Answer (score 7):

Use regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> len(re.findall('[lo]', "hello world"))
5
```

or `map`:

```
>>> sum(map(s.count, ['l','o']))
5
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, and since you are counting appearances of multiple letters in a given string, use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>>
>>> s = "hello world"
>>> c = Counter(s)
>>> c["l"] + c["o"]
5
```

Note that `s.count('l' and 'o')` that you are currently using [would evaluate](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#and) as `s.count('o')`:

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`: if `x` is false, its value is
>   returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is
>   returned.

In other words:

```
>>> 'l' and 'o'
'o'
```

Answer (score 0):

Count all letters in `s`:

```
answer = {i: s.count(i) for i in s}
```

Then sum any keys (letters) from `s`:

```
print(answer['l'] + answer['o'])
```

Comment: This is basically `O(n^2)` where `n` is the strings length, as opposed to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32414245/6045800) using a `Counter`...