# why in python "BABAB".count("BAB") is equal 1?

Tags: python

IMO the substring BAB occurs 2 times in BABAB
Why Python returns 1?

```
 print "BABAB".count("BAB")
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `count` finds only non-overlapping matches.

Comment: find what I was looking for at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970520/string-count-with-overlapping-occurrences

Comment: @Gnuz maybe do the research **before** asking next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) (emphasis mine):

> Return the number of **non-overlapping** occurrences of substring
>   *sub* in the range [*start*, *end*]. Optional arguments *start* and *end* are interpreted as in slice notation.

Answer (score 3):

`‍‍str.count` just returns the [number of non-overlapping matches](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count), if you want to get number of all matches include overlapping matches you can use regular expression with `re.findall`

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?=(BAB))',"BABAB")
['BAB', 'BAB']
```

And for count the number of matches you can use a generator expression within `sum` function and use `re.finditer` instead of `re.findall` which is more optimized in term of memory use :

```
>>> sum(1 for _ in re.finditer(r'(?=(BAB))',"BABAB"))
2
```

`(?=(BAB))` is a [*positive look-ahead*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that match the places which followed by `BAB`.

Answer (score 1):

String is "BABAB". By using *count()* it'll return number of non-overlapping matches like this: "BAB|AB", so it's counted only once.. Try with string "BABBAB" and you will get 2. Example:

```
>>> x = "BABAB"
>>> x.count("BAB")
1
>>> x = "BABBAB"
>>> x.count("BAB")
2
```