# Python 3 - count the occurrences of a substring in a string

Tags: python, string, count, substring

How do I count the occurrences of a substring in a string if they overlap?
For example: I want to count how many single Os are there in the string:

```
string = 'xooxxoxoxoooxxoxoxxoxxxooxox'
string.count('xox')
```

This way, it gives only 4, because where there is 'xoxox', it only counts once.
How can I make it work?

Comment: Have you tried doing your own algorithm? make a loop over the string characters and if it's an 'o' check if the previous and the next characters are not 'o's then add 1 to your counter.

Comment: I've made you a script [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970520/string-count-with-overlapping-occurrences/32925627#32925627)