# count() for continuous substrings in python

Tags: python

Why does the following program return 1 instead of 2 in python?

```
print "abcdcdc".count("cdc")
```

The substring cdc appears in two places(one starting at index 2 and the another starting at index 4). How exactly does the count() work?

Comment: Do consider reading the manual before asking, next time.

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970520/string-count-with-overlapping-occurrences

Answer (score 2):

May I refere you to

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=count#str.count

> `str.count(sub[, start[, end]])`
>
> Return the number of **non-overlapping** occurrences of substring sub in the range [start, end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

Answer (score 2):

[`count`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=count#str.count) only returns 1 because the value `cdc` overlaps itself.

```
abcdcdc
  |-|
    |-|
```

To get a value of 2, you need two non-overlapping instances of `cdc` or utilize a regex:

```
import re
len(re.findall('(?=cdc)', 'abcdcdc'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to count the total number of occurrences with overlap, you can do this with `re` module:

```
import re
text = 'abcdcdc'
len(re.findall('(?=cdc)', text))
>>> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `count()` returns the number of **non-overlapping** occurrences of substring. See [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count).