# Python string count not working properly?

Tags: python, string, function, count

There are two occurrences of 'aba' in 'ababa' (0th index and 2nd index):

```
myString = 'ababa'
print(myString.count('aba'))
```

Yet this code outputs a value of: 1
I know this issue seems really simple, but shouldn't the answer be 2 here?
If not, then isn't the count function not really doing what it's supposed to?

Is there a simple alternative?

Comment: It is correct. `ababa` - `aba` = `ba`. `ba` is not `aba`. So thats 1.

Comment: There's also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970520/string-count-with-overlapping-occurrences

Comment: if you did `"a".count("a")` would you expect infinity as the count? Why not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Python string function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.count)

> Return the number of **non-overlapping occurrences** of substring sub in the range [start, end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

`count` does not count overlapping occurrences.

If you want to count overlapping occurrences you can use regex with a lookahead assertion:

```
import re
print(len(re.findall('(?=aba)', 'ababa')))
```

Answer (score 2):

Documentation to the rescue: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

*Return the number of (non-overlapping) occurrences of substring sub in string s[start:end]. Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values are the same as for slices.*