# Trying to undertsand .count() method in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, string, methods

I was trying some question task was to find the number of times a substring appears in a given string.
Given string was "ABCDCDC" and substring "CDC"
I used the .count() method for string with gives me answer 1, which is wrong. So Please let me know the reason.

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37980892/11701071
check this out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String count with overlapping occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970520/string-count-with-overlapping-occurrences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs for [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) explicitly mentions this behavior:

> Return the number of **non-overlapping** occurrences of substring sub in the range [start, end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970520/string-count-with-overlapping-occurrences) for counting substrings with overlaps

Answer (score 0):

But if the example is "ABCDCDC" , then count is right... if you search for "CDC" explicitly.

"AB *cdc* DC" so CDC is just once in a string.