# I wrote a python code for counting subtstring in a string, I am getting a wrong answer for some cases

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Below written code prints the number of times the substring is present in the string. 
The code gives error for some test cases while correct answer for some? Please review the code.

```
string = input()
substring = input()
x = string.count(substring,0,len(string)) 
print(x)
```

One sample case where it gives error is [string - ininini and substring - ini]. It prints 2 as the answer while 3 is the correct solution.

Comment: You have to count overlapping occurences which `count()` won't do. See this answer on how to count overlapping occurences: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970520/string-count-with-overlapping-occurrences

Comment: `str.count` will count only _non-overlapping_ occurances of the substring.

Comment: Yeah got it. Thanks!

Comment: Also `count` will by default go from 0 to len(string), so you could remove those from the function call