# python text.count do no return the correct number of occurences

Tags: python, text

I have a question regarding the text.count() function in python.
Suppose I have the following text and I want to return the number of occurrences of "CCC":

```
text = "ACCCGTTGCCCC"
print text.count("CCC")
```

why it returns 2 and not 3?

Comment: "Return the number of **non-overlapping** occurrences of substring sub in the range [start, end]." https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970520/string-count-with-overlapping-occurrences

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of the `str.count` method:

```
>>> help(str.count)
Help on method_descriptor:

count(...)
    S.count(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int

    Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in
    string S[start:end].  Optional arguments start and end are interpreted
    as in slice notation.
```

So in your case there are two non-overlapping occurences of `CCC` in the string `"ACCCGTTGCCCC"`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, in case of overlapping string should I have to implement my own function or there are some built-in one?

Comment: @simalps you can use the Counter from collections, it will output a frequency dictionary

Answer (score -1):

```
Text.count()
```

returns the number of occurrences of the substring sub.
In this case: "A**CCC**GTTG**CCCC**" 
Gives you 2 because your substring is "CCC" collectively which occurs only twice in the string.(i.e. where "C" is placed next to each other at least 3 times.)

Answer (score -2):

Best would be to use the already available `Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter('test')
print (c)
>>> Counter({'t': 2, 'e': 1, 's': 1})
```