# Index error when trying to count occurrences of a string with overlapping

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, indexing

I'm trying to find the count of `bob` in `ls`.  I'm getting an "index out of range" error at line 10. And I can't figure it out. `i` should be 3.

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
ls =[]
for x in s:
    ls.append(x)
    print(ls)

for z in ls:
    count = 0
    i = ls.index("b")
    if z[i] == "b":
        if z[i+1] == "o":
            if z[i+2] == "b":
                count +=1
```

Comment: There's a lot to comment on here, but the biggest problem is probably that `z` is a character inside `ls`, yet you are trying to index it as if it were a string/list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [string count with overlapping occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970520/string-count-with-overlapping-occurrences)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to stick to the method you were trying to do by checking indexes ahead, you could do something like this :

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
bob_count = 0 
for idx, item in enumerate(s[:-2]):
    if s[idx: idx+3] == 'bob':
        bob_count += 1

print(bob_count)
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow/sept$ python3.7 bob.py
> 2
> ```

You have to watch what you are indexing and what you are doing to that index as well, if you are looking ahead say `index +1` and your at the final index its not going to work

Answer (score 0):

count() function of str in python.

```
In [31]: s ='azcbobobegghbobfdfdbob'

In [32]: print(s.count('bob'))
3
```

to find index of the first occurrence you can use index() function

```
In [34]: print(s.index('bob'))
3
```

to find the indexes of all the occurrences you can use re module of python

```
import re
In [44]: for val in re.finditer('bob', s):
    ...:     print(val.span()[0])
    ...:
3
12
19
```

Answer (score 0):

I just explain where and why the error occured.

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
ls =[]
for x in s:
    ls.append(x)
    print(ls)
#equal to
#ls = list(s)

for z in ls:
    count = 0
    i = ls.index("b")
    print(z) # !!!! z just a single letter,you can not use index on it !!!
    if z[i] == "b":
        if z[i+1] == "o":
            if z[i+2] == "b":
                count +=1
```

follow your idea,i think you want write like this:

**But it is not right**,because `i = ls.index("b")` never change,you match a same word `15 times`

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
ls =[]

for x in s:
    ls.append(x)
    print(ls)

ls = list(s)
for z in ls:
    count = 0
    i = ls.index("b")
    print(z) # z just a single letter,you can not use index on it
    if ls[i] == "b": #but ls can do this
        if ls[i+1] == "o":
            if ls[i+2] == "b":
                count +=1
print(count)
```

Be brief.

```
import re
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
print(len(re.findall("b(?=ob)",s)))
```