# count() method not working on string 'BANANA'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was coding in python to find the number of times a single sub string comes in a given string
I used the predefined method of Python3 ie .count()

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y08a5.png)The thing is here when I am trying to count the number of time 'B' or 'A' or'NA' occurs it gives me the perfect result but when I am counting number of 'ANA' present it should give me 2 but gives the output as 1

```
s="BANANA"
print("B = ",s.count('B'))
print("NA = ",s.count('NA'))
print("NAN = ",s.count('NAN'))
#Here the mistake occurs
print("ANA = ",s.count('ANA'))
```

Comment: Some research would reveal the reason, but I think it's a legitimate question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) counts *non-overlapping* occurences. The first "ANA" shares the "A" with the second "ANA", so the output is 1 instead of 2.

If you want to count overlapping occurences, see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970520/string-count-with-overlapping-occurrences).

Answer (score 0):

The `string.count(sub[, start[, end])` function counts the non-overlapping substrings. That's why you get only `1` as a result.

This is the documentation of this function:

> `str.count(sub[, start[, end]])`
>
> Return the number of non-overlapping
>   occurrences of substring sub in the range `[start, end]`. Optional
>   arguments `start` and `end` are interpreted as in slice notation.

See [string.count(sub[, start[, end]])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count)