# Why is count() method giving strange answer?

Tags: python-3.x

```
s = "ANANAS"
print(s.count("ANA"))
print(s.count("AN"))
print(s.count("A"))
```

"ANA" occurs two times in "ANANAS" but python prints 1 whereas
"AN" occurs two times and python prints 2. "A" occurs three times and python prints 3 as output. Why is this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count):

> **str.count**(*sub[, start[, end]]*)
>   Return the number of ***non-overlapping***
>   occurrences of substring sub in the range [start, end]. Optional
>   arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

The two occurences of "ANA" in "ANANAS" are overlapping, hence `s.count("ANA")` only returns 1.

Comment: then how to use count() when there is a overlap

Comment: `count()` is not the right tool for the job here. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970520/string-count-with-overlapping-occurrences) which shows different ways of counting overlapping sub-strings.

Answer (score 1):

This is because in your sub string ANA will be only counted twice if it's something like "testANAANAAN " I.e two full occurrences of ANA . 
As, in your case if it already checked first full substring it will  not use that string part again from full string and will look for matching substring in rest of string.