# Why does string.count() not give the correct answer if the substring we are searching for overlap?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, count

In the code, `count()`-ing "CD" gives the correct answer (2) but for `count()`ing "CDC" it only gives 1. Why?

And how to count "CDC" ?

```
v="ABCDCDC"
print(v.count("CD"))  #2
print(v.count("CDC")) #1
```

```
output
2
1
```

This works, but is there any simple string method to use?

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    #return(string.count(sub_string))
    #return
    n=len(string)
    m=len(sub_string)
    sum=0
    for i in range(n-m+1):
        a=i+m
        if string[i:a]==sub_string:
            sum=sum+1
    return(sum)
```

Comment: It doesn't count overlapping matches.

Comment: "Why was the function designed this way?" is an interesting question, but it's going to be hard to answer, since there's no justification given in the documentation or (AFAICT) the source code.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) states that `count` does not count overlapping matches:

> `str.count(sub[, start[, end]])`
>
> Return the number of **non-overlapping occurrences** of substring sub in the range [start, end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

Comment: While this answers the _why_, here are the answers to _how can I do it instead_: [String count with overlapping occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2970520/2745495)