# Is there a way to make a list comprehension from this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is a code I wrote to check for the number of occurrence of a sub_string within a string:

```
a = 'ABCDCD' #Main String
b = 'CDC'    #Sub String

sub_Len = len(b)
occurrence = 0

for s in range(len(a)):
    if a[s:s+sub_Len] == b:
        occurrence += 1
```

Comment: Why would you want to use a list comprehension, which is for *creating lists*, you aren't doing that here

Comment: I wanted to see if there was a faster way of doing it. When I timed the original code and list comprehension on jupyter notebook, the original code was faster.

Comment: If it's speed you're after, here's a duplicate with a lot of different methods you can test: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970520/string-count-with-overlapping-occurrences

Comment: _When I timed the original code and list comprehension on jupyter notebook_ - do you already have the list comprehension?

Comment: **maverick** answered my question, I have marked it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While list comprehension is not needed here, you can reduce your code to one line using list comprehension to count the number of occurrences of your substring

```
print(sum([1 for s in range(len(a)-len(b)+1) if a[s:s+len(b)] == b]))
```

Here list comprehension creates a list of `1`'s for every occurrence of the substring, and then `sum()` is used to add the count

Comment: Yea that's exactly what I was thinking, but I used the len() method instead.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a list comprehension, but it is shorter for your code:

```
a.count(b)
```

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count)

Comment: This isn't quite the same since it'll count _non_overlapping_ occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
sum(1 for i in range(len(a)) if a.startswith(b, i))
```

- We use `startswith` with a start index to avoid slicing the string.
- Technically this is a generator expression, which avoids creating an intermediate list before feeding it to `sum`.