# Wrong result in str.count() method

Tags: python, string, count

I'm confusing with a very simple string count operation:

```
s = 'BANANA'
s.count('ANA')
```

This should result in 2, right? Since the substring, `ANA` appears 2 times in `BANANA`.

But I've got 1 as a result.

```
>>> s = 'BANANA'
>>> s.count('ANA')
1
```

No idea why the wrong result. It is such a simple operation!

Appreciate any help.

---

**PS:** How can I solve this problem?

Comment: [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) say that `.count` only counts non-overlapping occurrences.

Comment: So, as a result, it's bringing only the first `ANA` because the second `A` is overlapped?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`string.count()` does not count the overlapping occurrences.

If you would like to count overlapped occurrences, a simple loop over the string will count it:

```
s = 'BANANA'
i = 0
cnt = 0
while True:
    i = s.find('ANA', i)
    if i >= 0:
        i += 1
        cnt += 1
    else:
        break
```

Alternatively you can use `regex` too as in @Henrique's answer below.

Comment: But only the `new regex` library, as I answered below...

Comment: @HenriqueBranco Yes. I was going to add that. But saw you added it already. Upvote.

Comment: This look ahead regex also works (old and new libs) - `re.findall(r'(?=(ANA))', s)` and shouldn't the `new regex` solution return 2 instead of 3 @HenriqueBranco?

Comment: It works and it returns 2.  Probably typo in the answer if you would like to edit @HenriqueBranco. I cannot edit since it is lower than 6 chars.

Comment: I made a mistake and already edited. Check editing in my answer! Thanks all!

Answer (score 4):

In 'BANANA', there is only a single complete 'ANA'. Count() is returning 1 because after it finds 'ANA', all that is left is 'NA'.

Answer (score 3):

Good question.  But Python string count() doesn't "backtrack".  Once it finds the first "ANA", it looks forward through the remaining two letters" "NA".

This kind of "forward search" is the same as most programming languages, for example Java [indexOf()](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-indexof-method-example/), C [strstr()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm) and VB.Net [InStr()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.instr?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Should I use regex instead?

Comment: I think a regex might help: you'd a) define the search pattern (e.g. "ANA"), and then b) count the number of returned "groups".  But you'd have to experiment - I'm not sure off the top of my head.  Please post back what you find :)

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem using the new `regex` library. It has a new parameter `overlapped` -- extremely useful.

```
>>> import regex as re
>>> len(re.findall("ANA", "BANANA", overlapped=True))
2
```

I found the solution at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970520/string-count-with-overlapping-occurrences) here in SO.

Comment: You don't really need `regex` for this. `re` can do it with lookaround. See [this answer](/a/48889434/4518341).