# finditer and findall jumping over substrings

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to find all the occurrences of e.g. `p='gg'` inside `s='ggggg'`. Based on my count there should be 4 since any position apart from the last one is a substring. For example `s[1:2]` is `'gg'`. However, trying both:

```
>re.findall('gg','ggggg')
['gg','gg']
>list(re.finditer('gg','ggggg'))
[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='ab'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(6, 8), match='gg'>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(8, 10), match='gg'>]
```

Seems to be skipping over potential matches once it finds some match. Also, as a result, the search for e.g. 'star' or 'start' is equivalent to just looking for start, since I would never find the second because the first is its prefix...

Is this a bug? How can I perform a full substring search ?

example 2:

```
>re.findall('star|start','starting')
['star']
>list(re.finditer('star|start','starting'))
[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='star'>]
```

(I am using Python 3, re version 2.2.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
re.findall('gg','ggggg')
```

result in 2 matches as `re.findall` does not look for overlapping matches, or as [re docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) says

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
> strings.

So this is not a bug, but behavior compliant with documentation.

If you are allowed to use external modules you might harness [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) following way:

```
import regex
print(re.findall('gg', 'ggggg', overlapped=True))
```

output:

```
['gg', 'gg', 'gg', 'gg']
```

Answer (score 1):

The keyword you might searching for is "overlapping". Here is a linked question [String count with overlapping occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970520/string-count-with-overlapping-occurrences).

From the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) documentation.

> find_all : Return all **non-overlapping** matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result.

It seem to be a feature not a bug.

You can implement you own search function like:

```py
def my_search(s, substr):
    for i in len(s):
        if s[i:].startswith(substr):
            yield i
```