# Given a binary string count the frequency of all binary number with various lenghts

Tags: python, algorithm, search, substring

Given a string like `'0100011'`
and a `length = 2` we have to count the frequency of pairs in the string: `00,01,10,11`.

`00 -> 2 , 01 -> 2 , 10 ->1 , 11->1`

The problem is if I just use the `count('00')` function, it doesn't work since it only finds  one occurrence: `" _ _ 000 _ _"`.

I've been wondering what the right approach to this kind of problem would be, since for the moment i've tried to create some sort of substring checker with 2 pointer(index and length) which goes back and forth to be sure it doesn't miss any combination but it doesn't feel right

Comment: [String count with overlapping occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2970520/674039)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how I did it:

```
length = 2
s = '0100011'

counter = {}

for i in range(2**length):
    b = f'{i:0{length}b}'
    for j in range(len(s)-1):
        if b == s[j:j+length]:
            counter[b] = counter.get(b, 0) + 1

print(counter)
```

will produce:

```
{'00': 2, '01': 2, '10': 1, '11': 1}
```

for length == 3:

```
{'000': 1, '001': 1, '010': 1, '011': 1, '100': 1}
```

...

for length == 7, obviously:

```
{'0100011': 1}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify  "  b = f'{i:0{length}b}'  " . I get it generate all the binary combination but I don't really get the syntax you're using. I always saw colon for slicing inside a [ ] but what is that and how is so efficient ahah, sorry but i'm not getting it.

Comment: @kindastoned basically this is one string interpolation formatter inside another. With the length equal to 2, the f-string of `f'{i:0{length}b}'` will become `f'{i:02b}'`, which formats/outputs the `i` in its binary representation, zero-padded to 2 character. See the format specification language [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: that's cool, thanks ^ ^

Comment: hey, sorry to bother but I might have another question, if the lenght is very long (i start getting problems for lenght > 20) my program takes too much time to check every combination. I was wondering do you have any idea how to improve the checking ?

Comment: I've clarified my question and posted the block of code I've done, I would appreciate if you go check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72986509/substring-research-of-a-binarystring-how-to-improve-this-program-in-terms-of-sp

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the number of occurrences of a single binary substring, you can use string slicing to get each consecutive pair of letters:

```py
data = "0100011"
target = "00"

sum(data[start:start+len(target)] == target for start in range(len(data) - len(target)))
```

This outputs:

```py
2
```

---

If you want to find the number of occurrences of all binary strings of a particular length, you could use a `collections.Counter` instead:

```py
Counter(data[start:start+len(target)] for start in range(len(data) - len(target)))
```

This outputs:

```py
Counter({'01': 2, '00': 2, '10': 1})
```

(Note that if you try to look up the frequency of a binary string that doesn't occur, the `Counter` will simply return `0`.)