# substring research of a binarystring. how to improve this program in terms of speed?

Tags: python, search, substring

A binary sequence S is stored in a text file. We are interested in the frequency
of segments in S: we recall that a segment is a sub-sequence made of
consecutive elements; its frequency indicates the number of times that
segment occurs in S. Take as an example the following text file,
named ‘ft1.txt’. The file contains the following sequence:

```
01010010010001000111101100001010011001111000010010011110010000000
```

The frequency of segment ‘00’ is 23. The frequency of segment ‘1000’ is 5.
Notice that the sequence is split into three consecutive lines.

Let min_len and max_len two integers such that min_len <= max_len. We aim at
extracting the segments of S that are of length between min_len and
max_len. Furthermore, we want to list the n highest frequencies and the
related segments, where n is a given integer.
Should only m < n distinct segments of length between min_len and max_len
occur, the output should consist of fewer elements (that is, only m
entries).

Design a function ex1(text_f, min_len, max_len, n) that takes as arguments:
- text_f: the path of the text file in which the binary sequence is
stored, in one or more consecutive lines;
- min_len, max_len: two integers such that min_lem <= max_len, indicating
the minimum and maximum length of the segments of which we want to
compute the frequency, respectively;
- n: an integer indicating the maximum number of highest frequencies we want
to report; and returns:
- a list of pairs (tuples of arity 2) defined as follows.

Every pair in the list consists of:
1) the frequency, and
2) the list of segments that occur with that frequency.
We recall that the list should contain at most the highest n frequencies
(or fewer, if there are less than n distinct frequencies).
The list is sorted lexicographically with respect to the first element of
the tuple. The lists in the second element of every pair are sorted
lexicographically too.

For instance, ex1('tf1.txt', 2, 4, 20) returns the following list:

```
[ (1, ['1011', '1101']),
  (2, ['0101', '0110', '1010']),
  (3, ['0111', '101', '1110', '1111']),
  (4, ['0001', '0011', '1100' ]),
  (5, ['011', 1000', '110' ]),
  (6, ['0000', '111']),
  (7, ['0010','1001' ]),
  (8, ['0100']),
  (10,['010']),
  (11,['000', '001', '11']),
  (12,['100']),
  (15,['01','10']),
  (23,['00'])
]
```

NOTE: the timeout for this exercise is of 0.5 seconds for each test.

This is how i'm trying to make it work.
The problem basically occurs for lenght >22 where i'm basically not getting an answer.
As you read in the exercise requires me to respect a timeout which fails.
So my question is how to improve this in order to make it faster ?
If you think my approach is wrong just suggest a better one and I'll work on it

```
def ex1(ftesto, min_len, max_len, n):
    result_list = []
    my_dict = {}

    file = open(ftesto)
    multilines = file.read()
    my_string = multilines.replace('\n', '')
    file.close()

    # creating b-combinations

    for lenght in range(min_len, max_len + 1):
        for i in range(2 ** lenght):
            b = f'{i:0{lenght}b}'
            # checking combinations
            for index in range(len(my_string) - 1):
                if my_string[index:index + lenght] == b:
                    my_dict[b] = my_dict.get(b, 0) + 1

    # formatting result_list
    # grouping by frequency
    def storage_system(sub_s, f):
        behave = False  # True for extending, False for appending
        my_tuple = (f, [sub_s])
        if result_list:
            for i in result_list.copy():
                if i[0] == f:
                    i[1].extend(my_tuple[1])
                    behave = True
                    break
        if not behave:
            result_list.append(my_tuple)

    for k,v in my_dict.items():
        storage_system(k, v)

    result_list.sort()
    actual_list = []
    if n > len(result_list):
        for i in range(len(result_list)):
            result_list[i][1].sort() #result_list[i][1].sort()
        actual_list = result_list

    else:
        for i in range(len(result_list) - n,len(result_list)):
            result_list[i][1].sort()
            actual_list.append(result_list[i])


    return actual_list
```

Comment: @S3DEV indentation fixed, sorry about it.

Comment: @KellyBundy ye sorry typing error, meant 23, you're right! by consecutive lines means just that in the file the one string might be written in multiple lines, that's why while reading the data i'm replacing "\n" with "" to get all in a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that runs almost instantly:

```
from collections import defaultdict


def sub_freq(text_f: str, min_len: int, max_len: int, n: int) -> list[tuple[int, list[str]]]:
    with open(text_f) as f:
        text = f.read().strip()
    frequencies = defaultdict(int)
    for part_len in range(min_len, max_len + 1):
        for i in range(len(text) + 1 - part_len):
            frequencies[text[i:i+part_len]] += 1
    return list(sorted(
        (f, list(sorted(k for k, v in frequencies.items() if v == f)))
        for f in sorted(set(frequencies.values()), reverse=True)[:n]
    ))


print(sub_freq('bin.txt', 2, 4, 20))
```

This takes the approach of just extracting all substrings of matching length from the source string and counting their frequency as it goes. Instead of coming up with all possible strings and then counting how often they appear. After all, why look for strings that aren't there? And you don't have to come up with all the strings in the text, you can just get them from the text.

A breakdown:

```
    with open(text_f) as f:
        text = f.read().strip()
```

Reads the text and removes excess whitespace (like a line ending).

```
    frequencies = defaultdict(int)
    for part_len in range(min_len, max_len + 1):
        for i in range(len(text) + 1 - part_len):
            frequencies[text[i:i+part_len]] += 1
```

The `defaultdict` ensures we can add to any position in the dictionary, if it doesn't exist yet, it will be initialised to a default integer value of 0.

The outer loop loops over all the lengths of substrings we're interested in, from `min_len` to `max_len`. The inner loop starts at the start of the string and goes up to the last index that would still allow extraction of a string of length `part_len`.

It then simply increases the count for each substring extracted. Every substring only gets extracted once, since we run through the `text` with each `part_len` and each starting index only once.

```
    return list(sorted(
        (f, list(sorted(k for k, v in frequencies.items() if v == f)))
        for f in sorted(set(frequencies.values()), reverse=True)[:n]
    ))
```

Once the frequencies have been counted, we need to return up to `n` of the found frequencies. By turning the values into a set, sorting them in reverse order (descending) and taking up to `n` elements, we have all the frequencies we need `for f in sorted(set(frequencies.values()), reverse=True)[:n]`.

Looping over those, the needed tuples can be constructed, taking all the keys from the `frequencies` dictionary that have a matching value - i.e. all the fragments with that frequency, sorting them and turning the result into a list with `list(sorted(k for k, v in frequencies.items() if v == f)))`.

The resulting list is then sorted as well.

By the way, you may want to point out to your teach that the outer list is not sorted "lexicographically" in their example, since lexicographical sorting would put `11` before `2`. However, I maintained the sorting you provided in the example, since I expect that is what your teacher is testing for.

A further simplication is possible by replacing the last part:

```
    return [
        (f, list(sorted(k for k, v in frequencies.items() if v == f)))
        for f in sorted(set(frequencies.values()))[-n:]
    ]
```

By taking the last `n` element of the frequency values sorted in ascending order, the frequences will already be sorted in the order we need them, thus removing the need to sort the outer list.

The solution then:

```
def sub_freq(text_f: str, min_len: int, max_len: int, n: int) -> list[tuple[int, list[str]]]:
    from collections import defaultdict

    with open(text_f) as f:
        text = f.read().strip()
    frequencies = defaultdict(int)
    for part_len in range(min_len, max_len + 1):
        for i in range(len(text) + 1 - part_len):
            frequencies[text[i:i+part_len]] += 1
    return [
        (f, list(sorted(k for k, v in frequencies.items() if v == f)))
        for f in sorted(set(frequencies.values()))[-n:]
    ]
```

Edit: since you asked for a speedup, I quickly ran `timeit` on your solution and mine and the result is that mine is about twice as fast for the example you provided (on my machine):

```
from timeit import timeit

print(timeit(lambda: sub_freq('bin.txt', 2, 4, 20), number=10000))
print(timeit(lambda: ex1('bin.txt', 2, 4, 20), number=10000))
```

Result:

```
1.039986400000089
2.2731566000002204
```

I also ran a test randomising the string and varying the parameters (for this I changed both your code and mine not to read from file, but accept a text directly):

```
from random import choice
sfc = 0
ex1c = 0
for _ in range(100):
    text = ''.join(choice('01') for _ in range(100))
    min_len = choice(range(2, 10))
    max_len = min_len + choice(range(2, 10))
    sfc += timeit(lambda: sub_freq(text, min_len, max_len, 20), number=10)
    ex1c += timeit(lambda: ex1(text, min_len, max_len, 20), number=10)
print (sfc, ex1c)
```

Result:

```
0.02489419999801612 7.395662600000833
```

Showing that my solution holds up very well under many circumstances, and with larger datasets, while yours starts to really struggle, as you experienced. (note that this also no longer includes the time spent on I/O, so computational differences are amplified)

Comment: wow thanks a lot. I must say your approach is way clever then mine. I knew I was doing some useless checks but didn't really knew how to avoid that. thanks again!!

Comment: You're welcome - the only reason I provided a completely new approach is because you clearly understood the problem and wrote a working solution. I considered providing some tips to improve it, but after looking more closely and seeing that you did understand the problem, I figured you might benefit from a clean and simple Python implementation. Thank you for posting a clearly worded question with working code, that was fun. Your code wasn't bad though - don't be discouraged about your own work by a solution that is shorter or faster, just take the time to really understand the new solution.