# Why doesn't the count() method work for overlapping substrings?

Tags: python, string

This is my code:

```
a = 'BANANAAAS'
sub='AA'

print(a.count(sub))
```

Why does it not print 2 as an answer since the substring appears 2 times? The first one begining in a[5] and the other begining in a[6].

This was a part of a larger problem where I have to generate and count all the substring in a string depending if it begins with a vowel or not.

Comment: It starts counting after the end of matching the first AA.

Comment: As to how to do it instead: [String count with overlapping occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2970520/2745495)

Comment: why don't you loop like this `[a.count('AA', idx) for idx in range(len(a))] `

Comment: `help(str.count)` says _Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in string_ (Note: non-overlapping)